# google map set zoom dynamically avoiding polygons

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, zooming

Eventually I talk nonsense: how can I set the zoom level in google maps, so all my markers become visible? I read examples using Polygon, but I assume that's a concept going to far?!

So is there a way to zoom dynamically without Polygon?

If not, is there a simple example using Polygon? I have an array called gMarkers which has a column for lat and one for lng. So looping thru that array would use gMarkers[i][1] and  gMarkers[i][2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps don't have a direct funtion for show all the "element"  in map .. you could do this getting the max and min lat and lng of all your markres  collection then use these max and min coord for build a bound

```
SW = new google.maps.LatLng(  your_min_lat, your_min_lng  );
aNE = new google.maps.LatLng( your_max_lat, your_max_lng );

bounds=  new google.maps.LatLngBounds(aSW, aNE);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Thänx again, that was new to me